# UIAlertController Alert action TextField need to be resized-error

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

Getting this error...

[LayoutConstraints] Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionViewCell that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing. View: <_UIAlertControllerTextFieldViewCollectionCell: 0x7fe6a9f26000; frame = (0 0; 270 24); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000098edc0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000007c5cc0>>

From this...

```
func saveText()
{
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "NAME IT", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

    ac.addTextField()

    let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "SAVE", style: .default)
    {
       [unowned ac] _ in
       let answer = ac.textFields![0]
        
       if answer.text!.count < 1
       {
          self.view.backgroundColor = .red
       }
       else
       {
          self.view.backgroundColor = .green
       }
    }
    ac.addAction(submitAction)
    present(ac, animated: true)
}
```

I have played around with this for a while, I have tried to figure out if I can add my own textfield to use it too...

```
func addTextField()
{
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

But no luck

I need to remove this error.

Thanks in advance

Oh, this didn't help at all
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-uitextfield-to-a-uialertcontroller

Comment: Set breakpoint on exceptions, then look at the call stack to find who is directly or indirectly trying to set the autoresizing mask.

Comment: Does this mean you can answer the question, gnasher729? Who is trying, you say? Load that into a completely blank project and you will get the message.

Comment: This is a bug in iOS and should be reported to Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help, couldn't waste more than a day waiting for a solution so I spent two hours on a workaround instead.

I figured it would be mean of me not to share...
OR rather nice that I spent the extra 20 mins to share my workaround.
If anyone plays hero and wants to edit this, I am happy to delete the answer.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    let textFieldView = UIView()
    let textFieldLabel = UILabel()
    let textFieldField = UITextField()
    let textFieldButton = UIButton()

    let WhiteUIColour: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    let LightGreyUIColour: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.921431005, green: 0.9214526415, blue: 0.9214410186, alpha: 1)
    let DarkBlueUIColour: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.01680417731, green: 0.1983509958, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

    let MediumGreyCGColour: CGColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7540688515, green: 0.7540867925, blue: 0.7540771365, alpha: 1)

    let bold17 = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)

    let hel17 = UIFont (name: "Helvetica", size: 17)
    let hel20 = UIFont (name: "Helvetica", size: 20)

   // Create button to present the UIAlert with textField workaround view
    let yourButton = UIButton()

    func createYourButton()
    {
        view.addSubview(yourButton)
        yourButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        yourButton.backgroundColor = .red
        yourButton.setTitle("TAP ME", for: .normal)
        yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saveButtonTap), for: .touchUpInside)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
           yourButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
           yourButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
           yourButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
           yourButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        ])
    }

    @objc func saveButtonTap()
    {
       saveName()
    }

    func saveName()
    {
       textfieldUIAlert()
        
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(200), execute:
       {
            self.textFieldView.isHidden = false
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(300), execute:
       {
            self.textFieldField.becomeFirstResponder()
       })
       })
    }

    func textfieldUIAlert()
    {
       view.addSubview(textFieldView)
    
       textFieldView.isHidden = true
       textFieldView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       textFieldView.backgroundColor = LightGreyUIColour
       textFieldView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    
       textFieldView.addSubview(textFieldLabel)
    
       textFieldLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       textFieldLabel.textAlignment = .center
       textFieldLabel.font = bold17
       textFieldLabel.text = "NAME IT"
    
       textFieldView.addSubview(textFieldField)

       textFieldField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       textFieldField.backgroundColor = WhiteUIColour
       textFieldField.layer.borderColor = MediumGreyCGColour
       textFieldField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
       textFieldField.layer .cornerRadius = 9
       textFieldField.font = hel20
       textFieldField.textAlignment = .center
    
       textFieldView.addSubview(textFieldButton)
    
       textFieldButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       textFieldButton.setTitleColor(DarkBlueUIColour, for: .normal)
       textFieldButton.titleLabel?.font = hel17
       textFieldButton.setTitle("SAVE", for: .normal)
       textFieldButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldButtonTap), for: .touchUpInside)
   
          NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
           textFieldView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -250),
           textFieldView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
           textFieldView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -90),
           textFieldView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 7/10),
        
           textFieldLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textFieldView.topAnchor),
           textFieldLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textFieldView.centerXAnchor),
           textFieldLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textFieldView.widthAnchor),
           textFieldLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        
           textFieldField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textFieldView.centerXAnchor),
           textFieldField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textFieldView.centerYAnchor, constant: -10),
           textFieldField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 33),
           textFieldField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textFieldView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 8.5/10),
        
           textFieldButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textFieldField.bottomAnchor, constant: 15),
           textFieldButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textFieldView.bottomAnchor),
           textFieldButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textFieldView.centerXAnchor),
           textFieldButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textFieldView.widthAnchor),
          ])
     }

     @objc func textFieldButtonTap()
     {
         if textFieldField.text!.count < 1 || textFieldField.text == " " || textFieldField.text == "  " || textFieldField.text == "   "
         {
             let TooShort = UIAlertController(title: "TOO SHORT", message: "\n\nTHE NAME\n\n YOU ARE SAVING\n\nIS TOO SHORT\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
             TooShort.view.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5818830132, green: 0.2156915367, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
             TooShort.view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
             TooShort.view.layer.borderWidth = 5
             TooShort.view.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.1491314173, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        
             func okHandler(alert: UIAlertAction!)
             {
                 // Do something if you feel like it
             }
             self.present(TooShort, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
             TooShort.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: okHandler))
         }
         else
         {
             //DON'T DO WHAT I DO, DO SOMETHING EQUALLLY AWESOME
        
             doingSomethingAwesome()
        
             DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(500), execute:
             {
                 self.textFieldField.text = .none
                 self.textFieldView.isHidden = true
             })
         }
     }

     func doingSomethingAwesome()
     {
         let saved = UIAlertController(title: "SAVED", message: "\n\nYOU HAVE\n\nSAVED THE NAME\n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
         saved.view.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.01680417731, green: 0.1983509958, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
         saved.view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
         saved.view.layer.borderWidth = 5
         saved.view.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.9768045545, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    
         func okHandler(alert: UIAlertAction!)
         {
            ...
         }
         self.present(saved, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
         saved.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: okHandler))
      }


      override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       createYourButton()

   }
}
```

// Actually took me 30 mins to post this, so if I've missed something, let me know✌️

// Because I have a scrollView, I figured this was next best thing to disabling it while that view was showing

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    textFieldView.isHidden = true
}
```